# Creating a C Struct From Go

Tags: c, go

I have struct in C that I serialize + persist to disk, and than read and deserialize, this is done usually in C code. now I need to write a Go code that serialize the same struct, so that the code in C can deserialize it as before.

as this is a fairly low level c, and I can't use any library such as JSON, it must be a "pure memory dump of the struct", also as I need the GO program to be statically linked I can't use CGO library.

Comment: No offense, but are you really sure? :) That sounds like a bad idea, in general. I don't program in Go, but the exact in-memory layout of a C struct is something that can be "hard" to figure out from the outside. Different types have different alignment requirements, and there is also padding. The choices made by the compiler here can change depending on *compiler flags*, they are not firmly required by the C language. So you risk doing something very brittle.

Comment: I'm agree with @unwind. However, if you know the exact layout (including endianness, padding, etc), then you can use [`encoding/binary`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/) package to serialize the data.

Comment: If it's a pure memory dump, you're not "serializing" it, you're just dumping the binary representation that happens to be there. That can easily break if you switch to a different compiler that aligns things differently. Theoretically it could even produce different alignment with different optimization levels of the same compiler.

Comment: In other words, serializing mean there is a protocol for converting to and from internal representation to a standard form that irons out implementation details like padding, alignment, endianness, number formats, etc. If you have such a spec, you should be able to implement it in just about any language.

Comment: [MessagePack](https://msgpack.org/) perhaps?

Comment: Thanks everyone, unwind no offense taken ;-) , I aware of the short-comes and the many pitfalls, as the I control the env. ( the c compiler and its configuration) I some what diminishing the  "britillety" of this solution. biosckon  MessagePack is too high level for me. Vinay Pai Thanks, that is the way I'm going to implement it, with a naive protocol.